# NHibernate output columns/projections of CreateQuery().list()

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have simple HQL query:

```
var list = OpenSession()
              .CreateQuery("SELECT MAX(p.price) as max_price, 
                                   COUNT(p.id) as count_all 
                            FROM Order o left join o.Products p")
              .List();
```

I would like to output "max_price" and "count_all" columns/projections as easy as possible.

Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(list[0]["max_price"]);
Console.WriteLine(list[0]["count_all]);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform it to Hashtable

```
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap).List<HashTable>()[0]["max_price"];
```

Comment: So I need to create a special class with projections first?(AliasToEntityMap??)

Comment: @knagode: No, AliasToEntityMap is a built in transformer; no need to do anything special.

Comment: Great! Before I had an error:The name 'AliasToEntityMap' does not exist in the current context. I had to change it to:
.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)

Comment: Should be Hashtable not HashTable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this but I think that you will need to create a class and project into that.
This is how I would start by approaching it

```
class UserStatistics{
 MaxPrice {get; set;}
 CountAll {get; set;}
}

var list = OpenSession()
              .CreateQuery("SELECT MAX(p.price) as max_price, 
                                   COUNT(p.id) as count_all 
                            FROM Order o left join o.Products p")
              .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(UserStatistics)))
              .List<UserStatistics>();
```

then it should be a matter of

```
Console.WriteLine(list[0].MaxPrice);
Console.WriteLine(list[0].CountAll);
```

[Great Post explaining better.](http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/nhibernate-setresulttransformer-and-dto.aspx)

Comment: Also I needed to add:
.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(UserStatistics)));

Comment: added SetResultTransformer to answer. also included link to a post explaining it better.