# How to show the result of nHibernate CreateSQLQuery in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, datagridview

I got a result of a query in nHibernate:

```
var result = _Session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT 'just a string' as Type, NAME  FROM SCHEMA.PERSON where NAME like ('%A%')").List();
```

and I want to show this result in a DataGridView. So I tried:

```
this.results.DataSource = result;
```

But this does not to work (It shows just a lot of stuff like "Length", "Long Length", "Rank" and so aon but not the actual sql result) as result is of type: System.Collections.IList System.Collections.Generic.List and in fact seems like a object array inside a object array.

So I tried:

```
this.results.DataSource = from res in result.Cast<List<object[]>>()
                          select new
                          {
                              T = res[0][0],
                              V = res[0][1]
                          };
```

but this only shows an empty control.

So how to show the results and as an advanced task how to show the alias/select result names as Column Headers?

btw. This should work for every SQL. So I cant use mappingFiles.

Comment: Use a SQLDataAdapter which fills a datatable.  Then make datatable the source of the DGV.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @jdweng: This seems not to work with nhibernate sessions...

Comment: The query is returning a List<DataRow>.  So you can use method DataTable dt = result.CopyToDataTable();  Then make datatable the source of the DGV datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: But as long a SQLDataAdapter does not work with a nHibernate Session this will not help me...

Comment: Looking at the source code it didn't look like the DataSet method used the DataAdapter.  It copied a List of DataRow into the DataSet.

Comment: I am open to any other solutions which - and this is important - is working with the result of NHibernate.ISession.CreateSQLQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search and help from this question: [NHibernate output columns/projections of CreateQuery().list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597042/nhibernate-output-columns-projections-of-createquery-list)

I found a solution that works for me:

```
var query = _Session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT 'just a string' as Type, NAME  FROM SCHEMA.PERSON where NAME like ('%A%')").SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap);
var result = query.List();

var tab = new DataTable();
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    var asHash = result[0] as Hashtable;
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in asHash)
    {
        tab.Columns.Add(item.Key as string);
    }

    foreach (Hashtable item in result)
    {
        var newobj = new Object[tab.Columns.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry row in item)
        {
            newobj[i]= row.Value;
            i++;
        }
        tab.Rows.Add(newobj);
    }
}

this.results.DataSource = tab;
```

Im sure that there are other (better) ways to do it, but hey: It works.

Comment: This solution doesn't preserve the column order which is a problem if you want to use auto column binding.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions do not preserve the projection order. I implemented this (ugly) data transformer to keep the order:

```
        Usage example:

        var command = "SELECT 'just a string' as Type, NAME  FROM SCHEMA.PERSON where NAME like ('%A%')";
        var query = _Session.CreateSQLQuery(command)
                    .SetResultTransformer(new DataTableTransformer());

        var dataTable = (DataTable)query.List()[0];

        Implementation:

        public class DataTableTransformer : IResultTransformer
        {
            bool _isHeaderRowAdded;

            public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
            {
                if (false == _isHeaderRowAdded)
                {
                    _isHeaderRowAdded = true;
                    return new Tuple<string[], object[]>(aliases, tuple);
                }
                return tuple;
            }

            public IList TransformList(IList collection)
            {
                if (collection.Count == 0)
                {
                    return new []{new DataTable()};
                }

                var dataTable = new DataTable();

                var headerAndFirstRow = (Tuple<string[], object[]>)collection[0];
                foreach (var columnName in headerAndFirstRow.Item1)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName);
                }

                var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = headerAndFirstRow.Item2;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

                int index = 0;
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    if (index++ == 0) continue;

                    var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    dataRow.ItemArray = (object[])item;
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }

                return new []{dataTable};
            }
        }
```